# Android - TabLayout not showing correctly

Tags: android, user-interface, tabs, appbar

This is how i set up my tabLayout:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    LinearLayout layout=new LinearLayout(this);

    layout.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayoutCompat.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
    layout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);

    setContentView(layout);

    AppBarLayout appBarLayout= (AppBarLayout) getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.toolbar_layout,null);
    appBarLayout.setLayoutParams(new AppBarLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
    layout.addView(appBarLayout);
    Toolbar toolbar = new Toolbar(this);
    appBarLayout.addView(toolbar);
    toolbar.getLayoutParams().height=150;
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    TabLayout tabLayout = new TabLayout(this);
    tabLayout.setLayoutParams(new AppBarLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,100));
    appBarLayout.addView(tabLayout);

    tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText("Tab 1"));
    tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText("Tab 2"));
    tabLayout.setTabGravity(TabLayout.GRAVITY_FILL);
    tabLayout.setTabMode(TabLayout.MODE_FIXED);

    final ViewPager viewPager = new ViewPager(this);
    viewPager.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayoutCompat.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
    viewPager.setId(24234);
    layout.addView(viewPager);
}
```

**The problem:**

I would like the tabs to fill the entire width without staying at the centre.

I get this in portrait mode, which is what i want:

[image: Portrait mode]

but getting in landscape mode:

[image: Landscape Mode]

Any help is appreciated, thanks.

**UPDATE:**

Things change if tabs become more than two! In this case i get same behaviour on both modes! Looks wierd...

Answer (score 0):

**SOLVED:**

Solution for me was setting two fields (private) of the class TabLayout, this has been achieved by reflection, with a custom TabLayout:

```
public class My_TabLayout extends TabLayout {  

public My_TabLayout(Context context) {

    super(context);

    initTabs();
}

public My_TabLayout(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {

    super(context, attrs);
    initTabs();
}

public My_TabLayout(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {

    super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
    initTabs();
}

private void initTabs(){


    Field field;

    try {

        int tabs=getTabCount();
        if (tabs==0) tabs=1;
        field = TabLayout.class.getDeclaredField("mRequestedTabMinWidth");
        field.setAccessible(true);

        field.set(this, getWidth()/tabs);

        field = TabLayout.class.getDeclaredField("mRequestedTabMaxWidth");
        field.setAccessible(true);
        field.set(this, getWidth()/tabs);
    }
    catch (NoSuchFieldException e) {

        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    catch (IllegalAccessException e) {

        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
}
```

with initTabs() method i fixed my issue (happening only with two tabs).

For more info:
[Solution](https://medium.com/@elsenovraditya/set-tab-minimum-width-of-scrollable-tablayout-programmatically-8146d6101efe#.les945z7a)